# nullable type and a ReSharper warning

Tags: c#, null, resharper, nullable

I have the following code:

```
private static LogLevel? _logLevel = null;

public static LogLevel LogLevel
{
    get
    {
        if (!_logLevel.HasValue)
        {
            _logLevel = readLogLevelFromFile();
        }

        return _logLevel.Value;
    }
}

private static LogLevel readLogLevelFromFile() { ... }
```

I get a ReSharper warning on the `return` statement about a possible `System.InvalidOperationException` and it suggests I check `_logLevel` to see if it is `null` first.  However, `readLogLevelFromFile` returns `LogLevel`, not `LogLevel?`, so there is no way the `return` statement could be reached when `_logLevel` is `null`.  Is this just an oversight by ReSharper, or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't get this warning using v4.5. What version of ReSharper are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like a bug in Resharper.

Note, however, that that isn't thread-safe.

[The best way to do this is to use a static initializer](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html), like this:

```
public static LogLevel Instance { get { return Nested.level; } }

class Nested {
    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static Nested() { }

    internal static readonly LogLevel level = readLogLevelFromFile();
}
```

Comment: that'll change when its instantiated + load it if its not used at all

Comment: `Cannot resolve symbol 'Instance'`.  Did you mean to do a `new Nested()` there?

Answer (score 4):

You could refactor it into something like this:

```
return (_logLevel = _logLevel ?? readLogLevelFromFile()).Value;
```

Alternatively you can use the built in lazy type (Requires .NET 4.0 or you can roll your own.):

```
public static LogLevel LogLevel
{
    get { return _logLevel.Value; }
}
private static Lazy<LogLevel> _logLevel = new Lazy<LogLevel>(readLogLevelFromFile);
```

Comment: That actually gives the compiler error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyNS.LogLevel?' to 'MyNS.LogLevel'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`.

Comment: @Sarah - Opps, I forgot the call to `Value`.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper wasn't 'smart' enough to figure it out for you.  It is kind of a complex thing to figure out, I would imagine.

I prefer @ChaosPandion's refactoring anyways...