# MSTest unit test passes by itself, fails when other tests are run

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I'm having trouble with some MSTest unit tests that pass when I run them individually but fail when I run the entire unit test class.  The tests test some code that [SLaks helped me with earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835671/nullable-type-and-a-resharper-warning/2835691#2835691), and he warned me what I was doing wasn't thread-safe.  However, now my code is more complicated and I don't know how to go about making it thread-safe.  Here's what I have:

```
public static class DLLConfig
{
    private static string _domain;

    public static string Domain
    {
        get
        {
            return _domain = AlwaysReadFromFile
                ? readCredentialFromFile(DOMAIN_TAG)
                : _domain ?? readCredentialFromFile(DOMAIN_TAG);
        }
    }
}
```

And my test is simple:

```
string expected = "the value I know exists in the file";
string actual = DLLConfig.Domain;
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

When I run this test by itself, it passes.  When I run it alongside all the other tests in the test class (which perform similar checks on different properties), `actual` is `null` and the test fails.  I note this is not a problem with a property whose type is a custom `Enum` type; maybe I'm having this problem with the `Domain` property because it is a `string`?  Or maybe it's a multi-threaded issue with how MSTest works?

Comment: How (if at all) are you setting up / tearing down between tests?

Comment: @Paddyslacker:  none at all.  I have no `[TestCleanup]` or `[TestInitialize]` methods.

Comment: Good unit tests are independent, so I would look at making these true unit tests by adding some setup and teardown to get your code in a known state each time. If there's a real test case there for calling the method concurrently or calling it twice, then write a specific failing test case for that and then make it pass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the other tests are modifying some value in the `DLLConfig` class that is causing the result of the getter to change. Unit tests should always be run from a known initial state, so you should either set this up in the test method itself, or in a method marked with the `TestInitialize` attribute which is run before each test.

Answer (score 5):

Your test is depending on an external file. Instead of calling a function that directly accesses the file you should have DLLConfig.Domain call a method in another class.

```
public static string Domain
{
    get
    {
        return _domain = AlwaysReadFromFile
            ? CredentialReader.Read(DOMAIN_TAG)
            : _domain ?? CredentialReader.Read(DOMAIN_TAG);
    }
}
```

Then you can initialize DllConfig with a mock/fake/stub CredentialReader where you can control its return value. Remember you are testing that DLLConfig.Domain is returning the correct value based on the `AlwaysReadFromFile` condition. You shouldn't be testing where that value is coming from (or if it even exists) at the same time.

Making your DLLConfig class more "testable" has the added benefit of separating out concerns. When you are thinking about a class and can't help but say "This class does *this* **AND** *that*" (abstracting configuration data and reading that data from a file) its a good bet the class is mixing concerns and trying to do to much. If DLLConfig is an abstraction of configuration data it should focus only on that and leave where the data comes from to another class.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the answers above worked for you, i solved this issue by adding `Thread.Sleep(1)` before the assertion in the failing test...

Looks like tests synchronization is missed somewhere... Please note that my tests were not order dependant, that i haven't any static member nor external dependency.

Comment: I spent a whole working day trying to find a solution. Thank you so much, this works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was using a non-thread-safe collection.  When I switched over to using a BlockingCollection (instead of a List), everything fell right into place.